# Сфера. как её нарисовать?

Tags: геометрия, glut

пытаюсь нарисовать сферу.

Делал по этой формуле

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код :

```
for (j = 0; j <= q; j++)
{
    for (i = 0; i <= p; i++)
    {
        vertices[k++] = R * cos((float)j /q * PI) * sin(2.0 * (float)i / p * PI);
        vertices[k++] = R * sin((float)j /q * PI) * sin(2.0 * (float)i / p * PI);
        vertices[k++] = R * cos((float)j /q * PI);
      }
}
```

вот что я получил:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Судя по коду, то у Вас u - это `2.0 * (float)i / p * PI`, а v - это `(float)j /q * PI`. Тогда в строке `vertices[k++] = R * cos((float)j /q * PI);` Вы вычисляете `R * cos(v)`, а по формуле должно быть `R * cos(u)`.

Comment: @EOF Спасибо. оформите как ответ чтоб я принял ?

Comment: Или в первой строке вычислений поменять косинус на синус и наоборот

Comment: @EOF да работает просто вы ответили и думаю галочка и решённый ответ должен принадлежать вам

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сравнивая Ваш код с формулой можно заметить, что ошибка кроется в первой или последней строке вычислений. Если в первой строке, то необходимо заменить `sin` на `cos`, а `cos` на `sin`. Т.е. строка

```
vertices[k++] = R * cos((float)j /q * PI) * sin(2.0 * (float)i / p * PI);
```

должна иметь вид

```
vertices[k++] = R * sin((float)j /q * PI) * cos(2.0 * (float)i / p * PI);
```

Если же в последней, то заменить

```
vertices[k++] = R * cos((float)j /q * PI);
```

на

```
vertices[k++] = R * cos(2.0 * (float)i / p * PI);
```